# R Installation of Windows RStudio Desktop ver 1.4.1106

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I'm trying to install an older version of Windows RStudio Desktop ver 1.4.1106 for compatibility reasons. I wasn't able to find any Windows ver, just Ubuntu. May I check if there's any official links available to install this specific version? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/ so doesn't look like it

Comment: might have a bit more luck by putting in a request at https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide/9 (there may be a reason why it is not shared -- is it this last version that would not plot ggplot2?)

Answer (score 0):

try here...
https://repology.org/project/rstudio/information

I am installing this version rigth now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29854646)

Answer (score -1):

Here you can Download all old Versions or R.

```
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I'm looking for RStudio